# Error while implementing MOXy's

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jaxb, moxy

I was getting a cyclic error in my DTO classes, so decided to implement MOXy's to get rid of it. I followed the following steps for implementing MOXy's:

1. Downloaded EclipseLink from [*http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php*]
2. Copied all the JARs from /eclipselink/jlib folder to my /WEB-INF/lib
3. For Specifying EclipseLink MOXy as the JAXB provider created a jaxb.properties file in the folder where all classes are present with following entry in it -

   ***javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory***

I am using @XmlElement and @XmlInverseReference annotations in my dto classes but I am getting following error while I am running my application:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions, Class has two properties of the same name "application"
this problem is related to the following location:
    at public thbs.provisioning.dto.ApplicationDTO thbs.provisioning.dto.EnvironmentDTO.getApplication()
    at thbs.provisioning.dto.EnvironmentDTO
    at public java.util.Set thbs.provisioning.dto.ApplicationDTO.getEnvironment()
    at thbs.provisioning.dto.ApplicationDTO
this problem is related to the following location:
    at private thbs.provisioning.dto.ApplicationDTO thbs.provisioning.dto.EnvironmentDTO.application
    at thbs.provisioning.dto.EnvironmentDTO
    at public java.util.Set thbs.provisioning.dto.ApplicationDTO.getEnvironment()
    at thbs.provisioning.dto.ApplicationDTO
```

Comment: Plz help me, I am stuck at it. Had this MOXy thing worked for anyone ?

Comment: Which application server are you using?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I am using Tomcat7 server. I was able to include MOXy's in my application, but it is not giving me the correct output. I have followed your both the links for implementing XmlInverseReference annotation: 1 (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-xmlinversereference-is-now-truly.html), 2) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313454/npe-thrown-marshalling-entity-in-jax-rs). But, still I am getting wrong output. I have added the xml response in the question. Please have a look

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan In the above two links you have followed two different ways for implementing XmlInverseReference element. Could you please tell me which one is the correct way ?

Comment: Both ways are correct, it all depends if you want the mapping to be writable in both directions.  I have added an answer to address the incorrect output:  I have added an answer to correct the output:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17545727/383861.  For new issues opening new questions makes things easier than adding to an existing question.

Comment: Oops.. will do it from now onwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your followup question where you are getting the wrong output.  The mapping for the `environment`property on your `ApplicationDTO` is wrong.  You could do one of the following:

**Option #1 - `@XmlElementRef`**

If you use the `@XmlElementRef` annotation the element name for this property will be based on the `@XmlRootElement` annotation on the target class.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "application", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@XmlElementRef
public Set<EnvironmentDTO> getEnvironment() {
    return environment;
}
```

**Option #2 - `@XmlElement`**

Alternatively you can use the `@XmlElement` annotation to specify the element that should be used for the property.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "application", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@XmlElement(name="environmentDTO")
public Set<EnvironmentDTO> getEnvironment() {
    return environment;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public List<ApplicationDTO> getAllApplications(){
    List<ApplicationDTO> allApplication = applicationService.getAllApplication();
    return allApplication;
}
```

*From here flow comes to the following class:*

```
@Override
public List<ApplicationDTO> getAllApplication() {

    List<ApplicationDTO> AppList = genericDAOTxService.findAll(ApplicationDTO.class);   
    return AppList;     
}
```

*Than to the following class:*

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = java.lang.Exception.class, noRollbackFor = java.io.FileNotFoundException.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> type) {
    List<T> list = genericDAOImpl.findAll(type);
    return list;
}
```

*And, then from database values are getting populated.*

*Previously i.e. before using MOXy's I used to get following in ApplicationDTO object:*

```
[ApplicationDTO [applicationId=1, applicationName=name, applicationDescription=desc, owner=5, createTime=2013-05-06 15:29:15.0, environment=[EnvironmentDTO [environmentId=1, environmentName=envname]]], ApplicationDTO [applicationId=2, applicationName=name, applicationDescription=desc, owner=5, createTime=2013-05-28 19:07:10.0, environment=[EnvironmentDTO [environmentId=2, environmentName=envname]]]]
```

*But, now I am getting following in the ApplicationDTO object:*

```
[ApplicationDTO [applicationId=1, applicationName=name, applicationDescription=desc, owner=5, createTime=2013-05-06 15:29:15.0], ApplicationDTO [applicationId=2, applicationName=name, applicationDescription=desc, owner=5, createTime=2013-05-28 19:07:10.0]]
```

*This is the actual flow of my application and object is getting created automatically using JAXB and Jersy libraries. I am not having any other seperate program for marshalling and unmarshalling the object.*

Comment: Implemented both the ways suggested by you, but still getting the same result :(

Comment: @Prats - Both approaches will work.  I believe the issue is that property isn't populated when you marshal it out.  How are you building your object?

Comment: I am using REST service and JAXB implementation with Jersey for this job. Please have a look at EDIT

Comment: @Prats - Can you confirm the object being returned has the missing property populated?

Comment: I am not getting environment details populated in the ApplicationDTO object. I don't know why ?

Comment: @Prats - How does the object get built?

Comment: Yepieeee, I figured out the problem. I was giving wrong foreign key in @JoinColumn(name="..."). I corrected it and now it is working fine

Comment: Thanks a lot for thinking with me

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, your `jaxb.properties` file was not picked up -- the "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime" in the error message indicates that Sun JAXB is running, not MOXy.

Make sure that `jaxb.properties` is on the classpath in the same package as your model classes.  If you included `jaxb.properties` in your source directory, ensure that it was copied to the same directory where your `.class` files end up.  You can read about setting up your `jaxb.properties` here: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/moxy/runtime.htm#sthref8

Hope this helps,
Rick

Comment: I am not getting the correct output. I have edited the question please have a look.

Comment: @Prats - I have added an answer to correct the output:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17545727/383861