# Marshalling Entities with xml inverse references involving a custom comparator

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, moxy

I'm trying to marshall an arrangment of 3 entites taking advantage of MOxy's @XmlInverseReference annotation. My scenario very much mirrors the example provided here
[provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313454/npe-thrown-marshalling-entity-in-jax-rs/3336327#3336327)

Entity A holds a collection of entity B which in turn holds a collection of entity C. The difference is that the collection of C in Entity B is sorted using a custom comparator. When I try to marshal the tree I get a ClassCastException where the collection in entity B is checked to see if contains entity A, causing the exception in the custom comparator which only accepts entity C

So here is the declaration of the collection of B in A

```
@XmlElement
private Set<AssignmentPeriod> periods = new LinkedHashSet<AssignmentPeriod>();
```

This is the collection of C in B which is sorted using the custom comparator

```
@XmlElement
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="assignmentPeriod")

@Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR,comparator=AssignmentPeriodRateComparator.class)
    private Set<AssignmentPeriodRate> rates = new LinkedHashSet<AssignmentPeriodRate>();'
```

And finally the inverserse reference to entity B in C

```
@XmlElement
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="rates")
private AssignmentPeriod assignmentPeriod;
```

When I remove any reference to the comparator, it marshalls absolutely fine, when I add the comparator annotation back in I get a class cast exception where the List of AssignmentPeriodRate is checked to see if contains an object of type CandidateAssignment

The stack trace is below. Any pointers would be gratefully received!

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: uk.co.rullion.mypayroll.entities.assignment.CandidateAssignment cannot be cast to uk.co.rullion.mypayroll.entities.assignment.AssignmentPeriodRate
at uk.co.rullion.mypayroll.entities.assignment.AssignmentPeriodRateComparator.compare(AssignmentPeriodRateComparator.java:1) [myPayrollEntities-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at java.util.TreeMap.containsKey(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at java.util.TreeSet.contains(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.contains(PersistentSet.java:171) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.CollectionContainerPolicy.contains(CollectionContainerPolicy.java:113) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ContainerPolicy.contains(ContainerPolicy.java:701) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ContainerPolicy.contains(ContainerPolicy.java:1) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:97) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:149) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:401) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:240) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:324) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:104) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:149) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:102) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:59) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:401) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathObjectBuilder.buildRow(XPathObjectBuilder.java:240) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:118) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:751) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshalStreamOrWriter(XMLMarshaller.java:1128) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:1079) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:1034) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:684) [eclipselink-2.5.1-RC1.jar:2.5.1.v20130824-981335c]
... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

---

### Update

This issue (see: http://bugs.eclipse.org/416875) has been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.5.1 and 2.6.0 streams.  You will be able to download a nightly build starting September 11, 2013 from the link below:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

---

### Original Answer

I have confirmend the issue that you are seeing.  You can use the following bug to track our progress on this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/416875