# Which Java XML binding framework supports circular/cyclic dependencies?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, idref

I've got two classes:

```
public class A {
  B refToB;
}

public class B {
  A refToA;
}
```

they don't have unique id fields (which are required for JAX-B XMLID and XMLIDREF).

Object instances:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.refToB = b;
b.refToA = a;
```

I want to marshall `a` to XML while storing the circular/cyclic dependency, something like:

```
<a id="gen-id-0">
  <b>
    <a ref-id="gen-id-0" />
  </b>
</a>
```

One of the frameworks I've found that supports this is XStream: http://x-stream.github.io/graphs.html

What other frameworks support this feature ?

Does some JAX-B implementations support it ?

Comment: If XStream does the job, why go hunting for something else?  This question is too open-ended.

Comment: @skaffman I would prefer if there was a JAX-B implementation with this feature

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAXB Mapping cyclic references to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073364/jaxb-mapping-cyclic-references-to-xml)

Comment: Seems it was almost exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073364/jaxb-mapping-cyclic-references-to-xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**MOXy** has the `@XmlInverseReference` extension for mapping bidirectional relationships.

**A**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {
  @XmlElement(name="b")
  B refToB;
}
```

**B**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B {
  @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="refToB")
  A refToA;
}
```

**XML**

The above classed will map to the following XML

```
<a>
    <b/>
<a>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Well, that result does not capture the cyclic nature of the graph? Where's the ID on `<a>` and reference to that on ´<b/>`?

Comment: The ID is not required. `A` references `B` through a containment relationship. Then we used @XmlInverseReference to indicate that when when `refToB` is being populated, that `refToA` should be populated as well. This strategy is also used by JPA implementations.  If you want to use ids, check out JAXB's `@XmlID`/`@XmlIDREF`:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago I worked with Betwixt. They claim support, see http://commons.apache.org/betwixt/faq.html#cycles

Alas, setting up a simple test did not work for me so far, output merely is `<A id="1"><B/></A>`, with the pointer to A in B silently *ignored*. There must be some mapping option that I failed to set...